# Как добавить элемент в вектор по указателю?

Tags: c++

Программа крашится в рантайме при попытке исполнить

```
 (*(this->loot)).push_back(item);
```

лут - это

```
 std::vector<Item*> *loot;
```

как сделать это правильно? если что, то код ошибки

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: @acade не помогло, та же самая ошибка

Comment: указатель битный, либо `this`, либо `loot`, смотрите в отладчике

Comment: А вообще вы тут совсем уж жестко поступаете: используете указатель на вектор указателей... Вы либо решаете ОЧЕНЬ специфичную задачу, либо, что скорее всего, делаете что-то не то...

Comment: покажите остальной код

Comment: А, ну да, я перепутал скобки. Значит смотрите не битый ли указатель. Но, все же, вы тут явно все усложняете.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну, мне приходится писать на плюсах фактически с нулевым опытом игру за неделю) скорее всего я что-то усложняю. Я просто не понимаю как иначе можно модифицировать поля классов, кроме как по указателю.

Comment: @Ivan Ну а вы бы не хотели сначала с языком то познакомится? Разобраться с класами, узнать про ссылки и т.д.?

Comment: Вообще это костыль, и целесообразно было бы воспользоваться `this->loot->begin();`